# cache C# property without extra field on the class?

Tags: c#, properties

I find myself often using the following design pattern:

```
public static class MyStaticClass {
    private MyObject1 _firstObject = null;
    public MyObject1 FirstObject => _firstObject ??= constructFirstObject();

    private MyObject2 _secondObject = null;
    public MyObject2 SecondObject => _secondObject ??= constructSecondObject();

    private MyObject3 _thirdObject = null;
    public MyObject3 ThirdObject => _thirdObject ??= constructThirdObject();

    ...
}
```

because I want FirstObject to return the same object (reference) every time it's called, but the constructor can only be ran when FirstObject is needed for the first time (because some stuff needs to be initialized first for these construct methods to work).

My question: I would like to keep a central list of all cached properties I have (e.g. so that I can set all caches back to null globally), and at the same time simplify the syntax (ideally one line per property, not duplicating the name in field+property, as I have lots of them) so I am hoping to be able to do something along these lines:

```
public static MyStaticClass {
    public MyObject1 FirstObject => Cached(constructFirstObject());
    public MyObject2 SecondObject => Cached(constructSecondObject());
    public MyObject3 ThirdObject => Cached(constructThirdObject());
    ...
}
```

with `T Cached<T>(T constructedObject)`. However this inevitably constructs the object again on every access, so it can't be exactly this syntax. I could make the method syntax `T Cached<T>(string s, T constructedObject)` and call it as

```
public MyObject1 FirstObject => Cached("MyStaticClass.FirstObject", constructFirstObject());
```

and use the string to check if I've constructed this object before, but that makes the syntax again more cumbersome, so I though I'd ask if there's perhaps a clever way to do this with less hassle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=net-7.0) to get a name of the property who calls a `Cached` function. So if you will have instance-level cache and you will not have any tricky overloads then property name may be used as cache id.

```
T Cached<T>(T obj, [CallerMemberName]string? id = null)
public MyObject1 FirstObject => Cached(constructFirstObject());
```

When called as shown `id` will be `id="FirstObject"`.

By the way, in this case you will create new instance of `MyObject1` on any call of the property. Property still will returns the firstly created object (if cache will work as expected), but you will create and then throw out the new instance on each call, because `constructFirstObject()` called before checking any cache.

To prevent such a behavior you can change the signature

```
T Cached<T>(Func<T> factory, [CallerMemberName]string? id = null)
```

In this case you will be able to check cache first and then call `factory()` to create a new instance only in case of cache miss.

You can also try to use other [caller-information attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/caller-information?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to build a better key for the cache.

P.S. Looking forward for [semi-auto properties](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/140) and `field` keyword which should finally solve this and allow to do something like `public string Foo => field ??= CalculateFoo();`

Comment: That was exactly the kind of thing I was hoping to find, thanks!!